# How to repalce HTML text with JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json

Received data from api and converted into JSON format, however every time I try to change a selected element in HTML I get either undefined or Object Obejct.

I have tried JSON.parse/JSON.stringify. I have tried innerHTML, innerText, textContent.  I have tried for loops.

```
HTML
<p id="lang">C++</p>
```

```
Javascript
let language = document.getElementById('lang');

let data = {
   "book": [

      {
         "id":"01",
         "language": "Java",
         "edition": "third",
         "author": "Herbert Schildt"
      }
   ]
};

data = JSON.stringify(data);

language.innerHTML = data.book.language;
```

Need C++ in paragraph tag to change to Java in data.  If Jquery would make this easier I would appreciate knowing how that works as well.

Comment: When parsed, `data.book[0].language`, the object containing `language` property is in an array.

Comment: `data` is not JSON. It's an object. JSON is a text format for storing or passing data.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data model you presented has `books` as an array, you'll need to get that out this way

```
data.book[0].language
```

`0` being the index of whatever book you want to display

```
data = {
   "book": [

      {
         "id":"01",
         "language": "Java",
         "edition": "third",
         "author": "Herbert Schildt"
      }
   ]
};

language.innerHTML = data.book[0].language;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not working as book is an array of objects, not a singular object. So you'd need to use `data.book[0].language`

P.S. You don't need to use `JSON.stringify` here, if you are receveing a JSON string from your API, you should use `JSON.parse`

Here is an example of the code running correctly:

https://jsfiddle.net/2et3zh7g/

Answer (score 1):

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string

So it seems your code is going the opposite direction of your stated intent.

```
let data = {
  "book": [
    {
       "id":"01",
       "language": "Java",
       "edition": "third",
       "author": "Herbert Schildt"
    }
  ]
};
```

After which, data already contains an object.

```
data = JSON.stringify(data);
```

And now, `data` contains a string.  So naturally, `data.book` will result in an undefined value.

If, however, you were to receive the data as actual JSON, such as

```
let dataJSON = '{"book":[{"id":"01","language":"Java","edition":"third","author":"Herbert Schildt"}]}';
```

You could then extract the language value using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) as follows:

```
let data = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
let bookLanguage = data.book[0].language;
language.innerText = bookLanguage;
```

Note the array subscript on `book`.  Since in your example, it contains an array of objects, you need to be sure to subscript into it.